# What's the meaning of '{}' in a find command?

Tags: linux, shell, find

I want to know what the `{}` really does and how it works in this command:

```
find .-type f ! -name '*.c' -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`man find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find):

> **-exec command ;**
>
> Execute command; true if 0 status is returned.  All following
>   arguments to find are taken to be arguments to the command until an
>   argument consisting of ';' is encountered.  The string '{}' is
>   replaced by the current file name being processed  everywhere it
>   occurs in the arguments to the command, not just in arguments where it
>   is alone, as in some versions of find.  Both of these constructions
>   might need to be escaped (with a '\') or quoted to protect them from
>   expansion by the shell.

and

> **-exec command {} +**
>
> This  variant  of  the  -exec  action runs the specified command on
>   the selected files, but the command line is built by appending each
>   selected file name at the end; the total number of invocations of the
>   command will be much less than the number of matched files.  The
>   command line is built in much the same way that xargs builds its
>   command lines.  Only one instance of `{}' is allowed within the
>   command.  The command is executed in the starting directory.

So what it does is to use the results of the `find` command as argument on the `rm` execution.

Then, the full command

```
find .-type f ! -name '*.c' -exec rm {} +
```

will look for files in the current directory structure. It will match those *not* having a name ending with `.c`. For all the results, it will execute the `rm` command, so all not `*.c` files will be removed.

#### Example:

```
$ find . -type f
./two/three
./something
$ find . -type f -exec ls -ltr {} +
-rw-rw-r-- 1 me me 0 Sep 30 11:37 ./something
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 0 Nov  1 17:50 ./two/three
```